Как получить текущую игру в которой находится пользователь в роблокс?
Нужно получить информацию о том в каком плейсе на момент запроса находится игрок, приблизился к решению через Presence Api v1, но максимум что смог получить это с какого устройства пользователь играет и время последней активности
Если кто-то сталкивался молю о помощи
Вот пример кода:

# URL of the API endpoint
url = "https://presence.roblox.com/v1/presence/users"

# User IDs to query
user_ids = [1667938990]

# JSON payload containing the user IDs
payload = {"userIds": user_ids}

# Headers specifying content type and Roblox security cookie
headers = {
    "accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Cookie": ".ROBLOSECURITY=_|WARNING:-DO-NOT-SHARE-THIS.--Sharing-this-will-allow-someone-to-log-in-as-you-and-to-steal-your-ROBUX-and-items.|"
}

# Send POST request with JSON payload and headers
response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)

# Check if request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    data = response.json()
    print(data)  # Print the response JSON
else:
    print(f"Failed to retrieve presence information. Status code: {response.status_code}")``` 
    


Рассмотрите внимательно /v1/presence/users, который позволяет получить всю информацию об игроке.
При успешном запросе вы получите вот такой ответ:
{
  "userPresences": [
    {
      "userPresenceType": 0,
      "lastLocation": "string",
      "placeId": 0,
      "rootPlaceId": 0,
      "gameId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
      "universeId": 0,
      "userId": 0,
      "lastOnline": "2024-04-01T19:53:00.069Z",
      "invisibleModeExpiry": "2024-04-01T19:53:00.069Z"
    }
  ]
}

Исходя из кода выше, заметно, что мы получаем из ответа gameId, placeId, universeId. Возможно, зная эти идентификаторы, получится получить какую-то информацию, однако в документации нет метода, который позволяет получить данные об активности игрока на сервере.
Также вы можете попробовать использовать библиотеку robloxpy. В ней собраны все актуальные методы и она очень комфортна для работы.
pip install robloxpy
